# I can't take a literal string on PHP 5.3

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying publish an automatic tweet using codebird.

My trouble is with the message.
I take the text from my DB an I put in the variable $mensaje, how you can see:

```
//Formato del texto
$Texto="$tit[title]: $bod[body_value]";
$MaxLENGTH=110;
$TextoResumen = substr($Texto,0,strrpos(substr($Texto,0,$MaxLENGTH)," "));
$TextoResumen = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($TextoResumen));
$mensaje = $TextoResumen." - ".$short;
```

And the array for to publish is the next:

```
$params = array('status' => $mensaje);
$reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
```

And the tweet is not published.

But, if I write text in the variable, the tweet is published.

```
$mensaje = "Hello world!";
```

or

```
$mensaje = 'Hello world!';
```

I tried all without success.

Do you have any idea for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information, the problem was the domain blocked in Twitter.
I was using the domain adf.ly for to share my twits.

Actually my code is the next:

```
//Carga texto
            $Texto="$tit[title]: $bod[body_value]";
            $MaxLENGTH=110;
            $TextoResumen = substr($Texto,0,strrpos(substr($Texto,0,$MaxLENGTH)," "));
            $TextoResumen = strip_tags($TextoResumen);
            $TextoResumen = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($TextoResumen));
            $mensaje = "$TextoResumen... $short";
```

See you later.

Answer (score 0):

I have added single quotes to access your array variables in your string, and used concatenation instead, and I have pruned it to `Maxlength` because I'm not sure what you were trying to acheive with the rest of that `substr` command. You can share if you like, but you want a tweet to be 110 characters or less, that should be enough:

```
//Formato del texto
$Texto=$tit['title'].": ".$bod['body_value'];
$MaxLENGTH=110;
$TextoResumen = substr($Texto,0,$MaxLENGTH);
$TextoResumen = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($TextoResumen));
$mensaje = $TextoResumen." - ".$short;
```

Comment: I tried that but doesn't work.
Now my codeis this:

    $Texto=$tit['title'].": ".$bod['body_value'];
    $MaxLENGTH=110;
    $TextoResumen = substr($Texto,0,$MaxLENGTH);
    $TextoResumen = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($TextoResumen));
    $mensaje = $TextoResumen." - ".$short;

    $params = array('status' => $mensaje);
    $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);

If I print the message the text is showed well, as this:

    echo "<br />".$mensaje."<br />";

Output: